# Type 'Observable<boolean | {}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>' error in unit test

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple service which post the data and return true otherwise throw error.

First get user data by getUserById, which returns Promise (User Derail)

then concatMap and call other method and return the result true!

```
// I want it's return type to be Observable<boolean>
saveUser(record: any): Observable<any> {
      return from(this.getUserById(1))
        .pipe(concatMap((data: any) => {
           // Some other code....
           return this.httpClient.post(`${this.API_URL}/users`, record)
            .pipe(
              map((result: any) => { 
                console.log(result);
                return true; 
              }), 
              catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
            )
        }));
}
```

I want, it's return type to be Observable but when I change to Observable boolean, immediately start getting error.

Just created the sample code on [stackblitz.com/][1], see I can I fix this?

Note: I cannot change any method except `saveUser(record: any)`

Comment: Need more info to be more specific, but the `<TypeA | TypeB> is not assignable to <TypeA>` occurs when you set the value to TypeB before later setting it to the intended TypeA. In your case you defined it as an empty object before giving it a boolean value.

Comment: Instead of defining `getData` and `any`, try defining it exactly as you want it: `getData(): boolean` and TS compiler should be able to pinpoint the error on where `getData` is returning type `<boolean | {} >`

Comment: @Z.Bagley: `getData` is an existing method returning complete user detail, already getting used from 100 places, I cannot change any existing code

Comment: Does it return `UserData` exactly (`UserData`, you mentioned `UserDetail` so checking there)? If that is correct, change to `userDetail: any` and check if it goes through. We can't tell what line the error is happening on, so if it still fails it may be in the utilityService.CheckFeature method itself. And that code could be useful if you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made the function like to work as a promise and use then and wrap the whole function with `from()` to return as observable.

```
isUserAllowed(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.getData().then((userDetail: UserData) => {
       return this.utilityService.CheckFeature(userDetail); 
    }), catchError(error => this.handleError(error)));
```

Comment: Did you declare the return variable of `CheckFeature` before setting it to *true* or *false*? You made it true/false, bang-bang. It likely is returning an empty value (rather than false) bang-bang, but your bang bang (`!!`) shoots it dead (turns empty values to false).

Comment: no, just added that operator to convert in pure boolean value

Answer (score 0):

You probably try to do something like that:

```
myObs: Observable<boolean> = isUserAllowed()
```

and

```
this.utilityService.CheckFeature(userDetail);
```

returns `Observable<boolean | {}>`

so `myObs` dont know what happens when `{}` arrives.

you need to cast the return value to the specific `Observable<boolean>` so typescript knows.

to something like:

`this.utilityService.CheckFeature(userDetail) as Observable<boolean>`

check this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bw7hf2